# Draw and Zoom over ImageView and canvas in Android

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, zooming

I want to be able to **draw** and **zoom** over `ImageView` and `Canvas`.

I can already do that, but when I draw something and then zoom an image - the drawing remains on its place as you see below:

[image: originalimage]

[image: zoomedimage]

and here is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enable_zoom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="disable zoom"/>

<com.zoomtrial2.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/zoom_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enable_zoom" />

<com.zoomtrial2.DrawableView
    android:id="@+id/drawble_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zoom_iv"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/zoom_iv" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button enableZoomBtn;
    private DrawableView drawbleView;
    private CustomImageView touchImageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawbleView = (DrawableView) findViewById(R.id.drawble_view);
        enableZoomBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enable_zoom);
        touchImageView = (CustomImageView) findViewById(R.id.zoom_iv);
        enableZoomBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.enable_zoom:
                if(enableZoomBtn.getText().equals("disable zoom")){
                    touchImageView.setZoomEnable(false);
                    drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(true);
                    enableZoomBtn.setText("enable zoom");
                } else{
                    touchImageView.setZoomEnable(true);
                    drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(false);
                    enableZoomBtn.setText("disable zoom");
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**DrawableView.java**

```
public class DrawableView extends View {
    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private boolean isEditable;
    private Path drawPath;
    private Paint drawPaint;
    private Paint canvasPaint;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private int paintColor = Color.RED;
    public DrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        setupDrawing();
    }
    public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }
    private void setupDrawing() {
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setDither(true);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }
    public void setDrawingEnabled(boolean isEditable){
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(isEditable){
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    drawPath = new Path();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        } else{
            return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**CustomImageView.java**

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
Matrix matrix;
// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;
private boolean zoomEnable= true;
// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 5f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
Context context;
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}
public void setZoomEnable(boolean status){
    zoomEnable = status;
}
public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(zoomEnable){
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                    origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                    origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled

            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                    viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
            * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
  }
}
```

Comment: did You resolve this bug?

Comment: did you get solution

Comment: News about this problem ?

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

When you zoomed you only called setImageMatrix(matrix). This set the matrix to the image which was then applied. The issue here is it won't apply it to the extra path you created. What you need to do is apply the matrix to the canvas paint the various elements. You do not apply the matrix to the path ever so they desync. Your drawableview onDraw() routine would be perfect for that code. You can also just draw the bitmap yourself too and get rid of the image view. After all what you're doing is more complex than just a view with some image hooks.